# How do I insert a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into a PostgreSQL configured Drupal installation

Tags: database, drupal, postgresql, timestamp

I'm using drupal and a pgsql database, but after long searches I still can't figure out how to put a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or now() into the database when inserting a row into a table. Putting now() on the default value of a column won't work, because drupal won't accept it on the database schema, so that's out of question.

The current column type is "timestamp without timezone" or "time without timezone", which drupal's schema accepts. Now the problem is inserting a date there.

I have tried:

`$now = format_date(time(), 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');`

and inserting it with the string placeholder '%s', but pgsql gave me an error.

I also tried to change the type to integer and insert using time() php function, and it didn't work (if it did i'd use it on other tables), so maybe i'll stick with the timestamp type as it is makes more sense.

Comment: I don't know about drupal, but have you checked that 'current_timestamp' isn't a string (must not be enclosed in quotes)? If you send the request as a string 'now' is allowed by postgres.

Comment: I found out how to add "now" do the DB, it's just like you said, instead of using placeholders i just pass a string 'now', and it works.  Right now the problem is i want to copy a timestamp from a table to another one, so fetching it is easy, but '%s' nor '%d' didn't work as place holders to the insert query.

Comment: When you have a time-stamp you must enclose it in single-quotes: '2010-10-10 14:13:22'.

Comment: The problem is it's not a know string timestamp, it's in a variable. Like this:   db_query("INSERT INTO x (that_ol_TS) VALUES ('%unknown_placeholder')", $old_time);           and $old_time is a timestamp i got from a previous select query.

Comment: Here's the error message i get from the drupal page:       Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "" LINE 3: VALUES ('www ', 'now', 'nothing', '0', '1', '', '') ^ in /Applications/MAPPStack/apache2/htdocs/includes/database.pgsql.inc on line 139.               As you can see, the last two fields are empty (%s placeholder), and those two are timestamps i selected from another table (they are correct, i can see on the phppgadmin)

Comment: You get the error "invalid syntax" because of the empty strings (not allowed). Check that you really have data in $old_time, and that it isn't an empty string. (also check spelling of placeholders and variable names)

Comment: Well, thanks, those variables were empty because i forgot to fetch the row, now it has data, but i'm still getting the same error, now with data:        Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "02:07:10.85615" LINE 1: ...ovacao) VALUES ('www ', 'now', '123', 123, 1, '02:07:10.... ^ in /Applications/MAPPStack/apache2/htdocs/includes/database.pgsql.inc on line 139.    So there are two timestamps there now. Now that it kind of worked i erased the db_query line and uncomented my drupal_write_record statement, its really more clean.

Comment: The error now is that you only have the time, not the date. Must have both for a timestamp.

Comment: Yep, that's it, while editing stuff to make it works, I changed the type to "time without timezone", and it should be "timestamp without timezone". They look the same when you are sleepy.. at least it's working, thanks man.

Comment: No problem, have been there myself :)  I made an answer with all my suggestions that you could accept if you want. Good night!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below you find my suggestions from the comments to the question.

- You can use 'now' as a string enclosed in single quotes, but current_timestamp should not be in quotes.
- If you have a time-stamp you must enclose it in single quotes: '2010-10-10 14:13:22'
- You get the error "invalid syntax" because the string is empty. Check that you really have something in the variables and that it's not an empty string.
- Your timestamp that you try to insert is missing the date.

Comment: It was missing the date, as it was wrongly type set as "time without timezone", and it should be "timestamp without timezone". The variables were empty, because i forgot to fetch the row. 'now' worked in both db_query("INSERT...'now' ") and drupal_write_record (good thing on this function is that you can forget the placeholders).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, that's what this site is all about! Now it's time to sleep for a while for me. Good night!